# ng-mouseover does not work

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I have a Controller with some functions:

```
'use strict';

App.controller('MyController', function MyController($scope){

  var showDetails = function(item){
      var element = $(item).find('.details');
      element.slideDown();
 }

 var hideDetails = function(item){
    var element = $(item).find('.details');
    element.slideUp();
 }

var log= function(){
console.log("sadsa");
}

});
```

I inject the controller correctly in my html since there is no error in the console:

```
 <div class="container-fluid team-section" ng-controller="MyController">
```

The problem is that when I am trying to trigger a function from the controller or even an alert() ng-mouseover does not work:

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 team" ng-mouseover="log()" >
```

or even

```
<div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1 team" ng-mouseover="alert()" >
```

if I use **onmouseover** it works nicely. Any idea why ng-mouseover does not work?

Comment: Can you set up a fiddle?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`log()` (and `alert()`) need to be on the `$scope`...

```
$scope.log = function() {
    console.log("sadsa");
};
```